# Creating algorithm with several conditions

Tags: algorithm

I'm pretty new to mathematica and was wondering if you guys could help me out.

Example:
We have the following coordinates:

- {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, where {x,y}

And I need an algorithm which returns (or prints) "01 Xx Yy" if the y-coordinate is the same as next in the list and if the x-coordinate is in steps of 1. If the conditions isn't true it returns "00 Xx Yy" and then "01 Xx Yy".

So the output would be:

- 01 X1 Y1
- 01 X2 Y1
- 01 X3 Y1
- 00 X5 Y1
- 01 X5 Y1
- 00 X1 Y2
- 01 X1 Y2
- 01 X2 Y2
- 01 X3 Y2

Thanks. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: As it stands, the question is not asking for help with Mathematica, but rather with the development of an algorithm. It is also not clear, what the expected output is if the first element of the list of coordinates is, say, `{2, 2}`.

Comment: You should be able to adapt `toString[coord_, validQ_] := 
 If[validQ, "01", "00"] <> " X" <> ToString[coord[[1]]] <> " Y" <> 
  ToString[coord[[2]]] <> "\n"` and `prints[list_] := 
 toString[list[[1]], True] <> 
  StringJoin[
   If[#[[2, 2]] == #[[1, 2]] && #[[1, 1]] + 1 == #[[2, 1]], "",
       toString[#[[2]], False]] <> toString[#[[2]], True] & /@ 
    Partition[list, 2, 1]]` to handle the case when the first line is not `01 X1 Y1`.

Comment: The first element of the list of coordinates should be "01 Xx Yy". I'm trying to learn mathematica because it's the program I'm going to use in the future. I can make the algorithm, but not in mathematica, that's the problem.

Comment: Ok, by the looks of your expected output, to get a 01, the **next** `y` coordinate should be the same as the current one, while the **previous** `x` coordinate should be 1 less than the current one, is that right?

Comment: it should not be 1 less, it depends on the x- and y-coordinates, but everytime the y-coordinate changes or the x-coordinates jumps in steps over 1, it changes to 00 Xx Yy and then 01 Xx Yy

Comment: You need to be very precise in your conditions. Consider the sequence of points `{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}`. And your condition in OP: *y-coordinate is the same as **next** in the list*... *x-coordinate is in steps of 1*. Now for `{3, 1}` you want `01 X3 Y1`. Because the next element is `{5, 1}`, so `1==1`, but the step in `X` is `2`, so clearly for the `X` value you are looking at the previous element `{2, 1}`, where `3 - 2 == 1`, right? So for each element you need to be looking both at the previous element for the X condition and at the next for the Y condition. Is that right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

To the extent that I understood the OP, here's a code.

First, the input list:

```
list = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}};
```

Now pad the list to the left and right with elements satisfying the conditions:

```
listpad = {First@# - {1, 0}}~Join~#~Join~{Last@# + {1, 0}} &@list
(* {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}} *)
```

Each element needs to be compared to the one before and after, so let's partition this appropriately.

```
listpart = Partition[listpad, 3, 1]
(*
{{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}},
 {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}},
 {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}},
 {{3, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 2}},
 {{5, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}},
 {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}},
 {{2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}}}
*)
```

The 2nd coordinate from each sublist is the one under scrutiny, its first element should be 1 greater than in the 1st coordinate of each sublist, its second element should be equal to that in the 3rd coordinate of each sublist.

Expressed in mathematica, this condition is

```
Last[#3 - #2] == 0 && First[#2 - #1] == 1
```

Let's roll this into a function which does stuff depending on the satisfaction of this condition *(EDIT: I've replaced `Which` with `If` as there's only two outcomes)*:

```
f = 
  If[Last[#3 - #2] == 0 && First[#2 - #1] == 1,
    "01 X" <> ToString@First@#2 <> " Y" <> ToString@Last@#2,
  Unevaluated@
    Sequence[
      "00 X" <> ToString@First@#2 <> " Y" <> ToString@Last@#2, 
      "01 X" <> ToString@First@#2 <> " Y" <> ToString@Last@#2]
  ] &
```

Now

```
f @@@ listpart // TableForm
```

returns

> ```
> 01 X1 Y1
> 01 X2 Y1
> 01 X3 Y1
> 00 X5 Y1
> 01 X5 Y1
> 00 X1 Y2
> 01 X1 Y2
> 01 X2 Y2
> 01 X3 Y2
> ```

The result of `f @@@ somelist` is usually a list of as many elements, as in `somelist`, so I use `Unevaluated@Sequence[...]` here, which allows the result of applying `f` to an element of `somelist` to be a *sequence* of two elements splatted into the output, therefore the output becomes longer than the input. `Unevaluated` is necessary, otherwise while defining the function, the `Sequence` would splat itself into the arguments of the `If` statement and not into the end result.